# Bootstrap HTML - my button will appear above my select list, but not below it

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want my button to display BELOW my select list. See the following code here-

http://jsfiddle.net/7jwap4pg/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <select id="company_name" name="company_name" class="search-form-select-list">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select A Restaurant</option>
                <option value="McDonalds">McDonalds</option>
                <option value="Wendys">Wendys</option>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="/search" method="get">
                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Search All" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It displays beside it instead. If I switch the order and put the button first, it will display above the select list which is the behavior I expect. So why can't I get it to display below?

http://jsfiddle.net/pu6vkrjc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your closing tag.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <select id="company_name" name="company_name" class="search-form-select-list">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select A Restaurant</option>
            <option value="McDonalds">McDonalds</option>
            <option value="Wendys">Wendys</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="/search" method="get">
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Search All" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I missed it.

*Your closing tag `</select>`is missing.*

Just as I note I wouldn't consider a drop down over a button a "Best Practice" for forms. I hate when people do that online. It just hurts the design part of my brain.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, in this case the button and dropdown are separate forms so I don't think it's as bad as you're thinking. I'll give it some thought though.